# import BrowserWindow in React Component

Tags: reactjs, electron

I am trying to import `BrowserWindow` inside of a react component file.

```
import { BrowserWindow } from 'electron';

class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  ...
}

export default SomeComponent
```

I am using `Webpack` and `Babel` to compile to translate the ES6 code. But, when I add the import statement, I get an error from webpack saying

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' /root_path/project_name/node_modules/electron

However, I use a similar statement in `main.js` in the root directory, and I was able to import BrowserWindow without any errors

```
//main.js

const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
```

I tried to use ES5 syntax in the react component, but still got the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem.

I can use `window.require` to import the `BrowserWindow` inside my component files.

For example:

```
const { BrowserWindow } = window.require('electron').remote;
```

Comment: When I try this, I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: window.require is not a function`, which is thrown by the renderer (React component). Do you know what may be causing this?